# HTTP-Error 500 in Openmeetings

Tags: display, ubuntu-12.04, http, apache-http-server

I installed OpenMeetings on Ubuntu Server 12.04.1. And everything was working fine until I came across the File Upload. I tried to Upload some pdf files for Testing. But after selection when I tried to Upload the File. It gave me this error.

[image]

Comment: HTTP 500 errors just indicate an error in processing the request occurred on the server. you will have to dig into the servers logs for clues as to what went wrong.